# RHEL8: locale vs localectl vs update-locale

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, locale

This is on the updated RHEL8 server.

I got the computer configured with non-english locale. The configuration seems to be consistent, e.g. 'dnf install' does not complain about anything.

```
[root@rhel8 ~]# localectl status
   System Locale: LANG=sl_SI.UTF-8
       VC Keymap: si
      X11 Layout: si

[root@rhel8 ~]# locale
LANG=sl_SI.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="sl_SI.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="sl_SI.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="sl_SI.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="sl_SI.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="sl_SI.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="sl_SI.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="sl_SI.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="sl_SI.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="sl_SI.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="sl_SI.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="sl_SI.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="sl_SI.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

[root@sumoutils-v8 ~]# dnf list glibc-langpack*
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Last metadata expiration check: 2:35:09 ago on ned 28 mar 2021 10:04:53 CEST.
Installed Packages
glibc-langpack-en.x86_64                                 2.28-127.el8_3.2                                 @rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rpms
glibc-langpack-sl.x86_64                                 2.28-127.el8_3.2                                 @rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rpms
```

To prevent problems with programs that doesn't like non-english locale (databases etc.) I want to change the locale (all settings) to 'en_US.UTF-8'.

However, after 'localectl set-locale' info from 'locale' is still the same, reboot does not help. I have read about 'update-locale' command but it does not exists on my RHEL8 and I do not know hot to install it.

```
[root@rhel8 ~]# localectl set-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8

[root@rhel8 ~]# localectl status
   System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
       VC Keymap: si
      X11 Layout: si

[root@rhel8 ~]# locale
LANG=sl_SI.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="sl_SI.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="sl_SI.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="sl_SI.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="sl_SI.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="sl_SI.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="sl_SI.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="sl_SI.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="sl_SI.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="sl_SI.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="sl_SI.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="sl_SI.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="sl_SI.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I need some explanation about what's going on and how to proceed.

Comment: Most likely there are other files exporting a different LANG. It's an env var after all. localectl only reports value set in the file it uses, not the value that is currently / ultimately used / applied. Try to use find and grep to check dot files in your /root and files in /etc.

Comment: Correct! Lines started with "AcceptEnv" in /etc/ssh/sshd_config will result in copying local env to the server. That can make troubles if the corresponding glibc-langpack is not installed. I am thinking about commenting out all AcceptEnv lines in sshd_config (including XMODIFIERS) to make all the different users uniform experience on the server. Could there be something wrong with this?

Answer (score 1):

A desktop environment will override the system locale, if you are using it.

For KDE5 you can use can find the relevant settings in Regional Settings/Formats/Region. It is written to `~/.config/plasma-localerc`.

In GNOME you will find them in [GNOME Control Center/Region & Language](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_basic_system_settings/assembly_changing-basic-environment-settings_configuring-basic-system-settings).